# Using argparse or docopt for pdftk replacement

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse, docopt

I have am writing a program that accepts arguements in the following form.

```
SYNOPSIS
pdf_form.py <input PDF file | - | PROMPT> [ <operation> <operation arguments> ]
    [ output <output filename | - | PROMPT> ] [ flatten ]
Where:
    <operation> may be empty, or: [generate_fdf | fill_form |dump_data | dump_data_fields ]
OPTIONS
--help, -h
    show summary of options.

<input PDF files | - | PROMPT>
    An input PDF file. Use - to pass a single PDF into pdftk via stdin.

[<operation> <operation arguments>]
    Available operations are:
    generate_fdf,fill_form, dump_data,dump_data_fields
    Some operations takes additional arguments, described below.

    generate_fdf
        Reads a single, input PDF file and generates an FDF file suitable for fill_form out of it
        to the given output filename or (if no output is given) to stdout. Does not create a new PDF.

    fill_form <FDF data filename | - | PROMPT>
        Fills the input PDF's form fields with the data from an FDF file, or stdin.
        Enter the data filename after fill_form, or use - to pass the data via stdin, like so:

        ./pdf_form.py form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output form.filled.pdf

        After filling a form, the form fields remain interactive unless flatten is used.
        flatten merges the form fields with the PDF pages. You can also use flatten alone, as shown:

        ./pdf_form.py form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output out.pdf flatten

        or:

        ./pdf_form.py form.filled.pdf output out.pdf flatten

    dump_data
        Reads a single, input PDF file and reports various statistics,  to the given output filename or (if no output is given).

    dump_data_fields
         Reads a single, input PDF file and reports form field statistics to the given output filename

[flatten]
    Use this option to merge an input PDF's interactive form fields and their data with the PDF's pages.
```

I am currently parsing these options using the following (messy) code

```
def parse(arg):
    """ Parses commandline arguments. """
    #checking that request is valid
    if len(arg) == 1:
        raise ValueError(info())
    if arg[1] in ('-h', '--help'):
        print(info(verbose=True))
        return
    if len(arg) == 2:
        raise ValueError(info())

    path = arg[1]
    if path == 'PROMPT':
        path = input('Please enter a filename for an input document:')

    func = arg[2]

    if func == 'fill_form':
        fdf = arg[3]
        if len(arg) > 5 and arg[4] == 'output':
            out = arg[5]
        else:
            out = '-'
    else:
        fdf = None
        if len(arg) > 4 and arg[3] == 'output':
            out = arg[4]
        else:
            out = '-'

    if out == 'PROMPT':
        out = input('Output file: ')

    flatten = 'flatten' in arg

    return path, func, fdf, out, flatten
```

Is there a better way to do this with either argparse or docopt?

Comment: `argparse` won't ask for any `inputs`.  It can look at the `sys.argv` strings, and assign values to attributes like `args.path`, `args.func`.  But any further input from the user has to be fetched after parsing is done.

Comment: The issue I was having was making it work so it would need an fdf if func='fill_fom' and it wouldn't look for one otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

One argument could be

```
parser.add_argument('-o','--output', default='-')
```

and later

```
if args.output in ['PROMPT']:
    ... input...
```

others:

```
parser.add_argument('--flatten', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--fill_form', dest='ftd')
parser.add_argument('--path')

if args.path in ['PROMPT']:
     args.path = input...
```

Comment: what does `dest='ftd'` do?

Comment: It puts the value in `args.ftd` rather than `args.fill_form`; it lets you use one string as the flag, and other as the attribute name.

Comment: I'll play with this to see if I can make it work. Thank you

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that things like flatten need to be treated as optional positional argument (`flattten`, not `--flatten`). If I were making this for the first time, this would be easy, but I am making a replacement for an existing piece of software.

Comment: Your `operation` part looks like it could be cast as `subparsers`.  But that argument is - to the main parser - a required positional.  `subparsers` don't play nicely with optional (`nargs='?'`) positionals.  If you can't change the existing specs, and those specs deviate from common UNIX practice, it is hard to use `argparse`.

Comment: I think my original code will be what's parsing args than. Thank you for the help.